# How to insert or delete data into mongodb collections in existing array for nodejs API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hop you are good and i think i can get here a proper solutions. I have simple mongoDB and Node Js API. So my problem is In my database collections has multiple product and each product has an **review** array. When i try to update or delete any data into the reviews array element it's show the message into console **"Record added as  { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }"**. but i want to insert and delete data successfully into the reviews array. Please see my functions and methods below:

**For Route :**

```
app.put('/notes/insertarray', notes.insertToArray);
```

**For Controller :**

```
exports.insertToArray = function(req, err, res) {   
    var title = req.body.title;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var comment = req.body.comment;
    var stars = req.body.stars;
    var date = req.body.date;
    Note.update(
        {title:title},
        {$push:{
            reviews:{
                $each:[
                    {
                        "name":name,
                        "comment":comment,
                        "stars":stars,
                        "date":date
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        },function(err, results){
        console.log("Record added as ", results);
        res(results);
    });
};
```

**And My data model is like below :**

```
  {
    "title": "Coffee Mug",
    "slogan": "Keep your coffee hot!",
    "description": "A mug is a type of cup used for drinking hot beverages, such as coffee, tea, hot chocolate or soup. Mugs usually have handles, and hold a larger amount of fluid than other types of cup. Usually a mug holds approximately 12 US fluid ounces (350 ml) of liquid; double a tea cup. A mug is a less formal style of drink container and is not usually used in formal place settings, where a teacup or coffee cup is preferred.",
    "stars": 0,
    "category": "Kitchen",
    "img_url": "/img/products/mug.jpg",
    "price": 12.5,
    "reviews": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "comment": "",
        "stars": 5,
        "date": 1456067725049
      },{
        "name": "",
        "comment": "",
        "stars": 5,
        "date": 1456067725059
      }
    ]
  }
```

**And Post Man Request**

```
{
    "title": "Coffee Mug",
    "name": "this is slogan2",
    "comment": "This is description",
    "stars": 3.4,
    "date": 220
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$each used if you pass array
As this is json , so no need of $each

```
{$push:{
            reviews:{
                        "name":name,
                        "comment":comment,
                        "stars":stars,
                        "date":date
                     }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. But there will be an review array but i was mistake it. Please see it again if possible

Comment: have you defined it in model(Note)

Comment: RITESH ARORA Thank you so much for your help and finally it's working